# Why deities are called asuras in rig-veda why it became a symbol of demons in post-rigvedic period?

Tags: scripture, vedas, gods, rig-veda, asuras

Why deities are called asuras in rig-veda why it became a symbol of demons in post-rigvedic period?

> 7 He, strong of wing, hath lightened
>   up the regions, deep-quivering
>   **Asura**, the gentle Leader.
>   Where now is Sūrya, where is one to
>   tell us to what celestial sphere his
>   ray hath wandered?
>
> **— rigveda:book1:HYMN XXXV**

source:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01035.htm

> 4 As with a bolt, Bṛhaspati, fiercely
>   flaming, pierce thou Vṛkadvaras’, the
>   **Asura's, heroes.**
>   Even as in time of old with might
>   thou slewest, so slay even now our
>   enemy, O Indra.
>
> **— Rig-Veda:Book 2: HYMN XXX**

source:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02030.htm

Is there a story behind that? from brahmanas and aranyaks or from anywhere else. I have read a wikipedia article but still wants other answers.

**UPDATE**

I found that the word asura is used for gods even in *saamveda* too.

> **XII Indra**
>
> 1. O Indra, thou art far-renowned,
>      impetuous Lord of power and might.
>      Alone, the never-conquered
>      guardian of mankind, thou smitest
>      down resistless foes.
> 2. As such we seek thee now, **O
>      Asura**, the most wise, craving thy
>      bounty as our share
>      Thy sheltering defence is like an
>      ample cloak. So may thy favours
>      reach to us.
>
> **—samaveda:part1:book6:chapterII:XII**

source:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sv.htm

but that is not connected to evil:—

> हिरण्यहस्तोअसुरःसुनीथः सुमृळीकः स्ववाँ यात्वर्वाङ् ।अपसेधन्रक्षसो यातुधानानस्थाद्देवः प्रतिदोषं गृणानः ॥१०॥
>
> May he, gold-handed **Asura**, kind leader, come hither to us with his help and favour.Driving off **Raksasas and Yatudhanas**, [he] the god is present, praised inhymns at evening.
>
> – Translated by Ralph Griffith
>
> **— Rigveda 1.35.10**

Comment: mainly in puranic literature ,,,

Comment: In Samudra Manthana, the goddess Varunai, the goddess of sura, came out. The gods readily accepted her and thus they came to be known as Suras. But the demons rejected Varunai and were therefore known as Asuras... - Agni Purana

Comment: @Rakesh joshi means vedas,aranyakas,brahmanas and principal upnishads don't give an answer to this right? ;)

Comment: @Fiercelord it Maybe possible. But mainly in puranas asura is referred as demons.

Comment: An interesting aside - in Zorastrianism - Good and God is Asura and the evil Deivas. Their Gor is Ahura Mazda - Parsee (Farsi) does not have the alphabet 'sa' instead they use 'ha' - so is God then an Asura? and now the query about how deities called 'Asuras' in rig Veda became Demons!!!! Interesting!

Comment: @Suresh Ramaswamy i don't think it a has any ralation with zoroastriasm becase **vedic relegion** is far more old but yes really you will surprise that there are many things present in vedas but but absent in later ages like maruts are called sons of rudra in vedic age but in post-vedic as kashyapa sons. :)

Comment: @Fierce lord okay, but Zoroastrianism is an equally old religion with overlapping beliefs with Sanatana Dharma. Following Western Scholars(though I don't always accept their timelines) the Vedas were composed between 2000 to 1500 BCE - Atharva Veda as late as 1000 BCE and Zoroastrianism has been around from the second millennium BCE - therefore they are co-extant.  Our faith and Puranas tell that Sanatana Dharma is much, much older!!!

Comment: @Suresh Ramaswamy Reall friend i will not talk about why indo-iranians are not older than what we call indo-aryans if you wish then comment. :)

Comment: @Suresh Ramaswamy I think what we call indo-aryans were just migrating herds as we know as the course of yamuna and satluj moved eastwards saraswati river dried IVC migrated to east this is mentioned in scriptures the drying up of saraswati river and geographically too in west checked by satelite that ghakar-hakar river system dried around 1900 bc and vedas do mention saraswati but not drying means when  vedas were composed it was flowing. and what we call B.M.A.C from where indo-aryans may have came to india have trading relations with IVC. And rejecting an 'invasion' theory there is a 'conti

Comment: oh sorry 'continuity theory' according to which diffrent style of pottery both IVC and indo-aryan were practicing and no  of sites incresed and IVC had already ruralized.

Comment: And that above comment it is all not related to that " @Suresh Ramaswamy Reall
friend i will not talk about". ;)

Answer (score 6):

The word Asura can have many meanings. Primary being this - A-Sura or not Sura".

In this sense, the word is used in the Yajur Veda (here KYV denotes the Krishna Yajur Veda) too. Where the word is simply meaning a demon who is always an enemy of the Gods.

> **DevAsurA** eshu lokesh vaspardanta sa etam vishnurvAmanapashyattam swAyei devatAyA Ahalabhata tato vai sa imA .....||
>
> Once there was a conflict between the Devas and the Asuras regarding
>   some Vishya ( lokeshu vijaya bhuteshu i.e for gaining supremacy over
>   the worlds). Vishnu then had seen VAmana or "short in stature"
>   animals. THose (i.e such short statured animals) are then offered to
>   Vishnu. Thereafter Vishnu won over the three worlds. Thus, whoever
>   (who's having conflicts regarding their possesions like house, lands
>   etc) person, who offers such short animals to Vishnu can similarly
>   attain Vishnu-hood and win over the three worlds....
>
> **KYV 2nd KAnda, 1st PrapAthaka, 3rd AnuvAka**.

SAyanAchArya says on this AnuvAka-

> "Tritiya anuvAke jayAdihetun pashunanvidhitsannAdau lokatraya jaya
>   hetum pasum vidhAtum prastauti..."
>
> OR
>
> In this 3rd anuvAka, description of animals that are to be offered for
>   winning over the three worlds, are described...

Similarly, see the following Mantra:

> PrajApatir **devAsurAn**asrijata tadanu yajno hasrijyata yajyam
>   chandAmsi te vishvancha vyakrAmanat ......
>
> During some ancient time in the past (PurAkAla), PrajApati did create
>   the DevAs and the Asuras and thereafter created Yajna (sacrifice). And, as an
>   allied part of Yajna, he created the Chandas too...
>
> **KYV 3rd KAnda, 3rd PrapAthaka, 7th AnuvAka.**

And, for this AnuvAka, SAyana says:

> Atha Saptame somangatvenAha shrAvayetyAdayo mantrA vidhiyate
>
> OR
>
> In this 7th AnuvAka, Mantras like "AshrAvan..", are stated, as part of
>   SomA-Yajna.

So, "Asura" as meaning a "demon", is used in the Vedas as well and not just in the ItihAsa-PurAnas

Comment: after a long time but, I think it's not completly correct and i asked for rigveda and samaveda as above till yajurveda the meaning was reverted in question too rigveda i mentioned. so its not correct because it is mot based either on rigveda and samaveda.
**Indra the king of gods is called asura** in rigveda and  samaveda.

Comment: @Fiercelord I have the whole Krishna Yajurveda book, and i'm quoting from it.. so it is true that asura as a demon is mentioned in KYV at least.. whether it's not found at all in RV or not, i can not tell for sure.. because i have not read the whole RV yet..Anyways may update it later..

Answer (score 0):

The word **asura** is used in rigveda and samaveda as an meaning,"lord" or some kind of praise as if it was a bad it was  used for vritra too in rigveda but the word deva represents the original special designation for devas and adeva or only asura remaining for daityas.

The story from chandogya upnishad which i already gave in previous answer when merged with wikipedia gave rise to it.
So, the gods were those who got the true knowledge and where the asuras went with their bad philosphy became ungodly and thus having their previous designation while their brothers devas brcome deva (godly).

> ये **देवा** सो दिव्येकादश
>   स्थ पृथिव्यामध्येकादश
>   स्थ ।
>   अप्सुक्षितो महिनैकादश
>   स्थ ते देवासो यज्ञमिमं
>   जुषध्वम् ॥११॥
>
> O ye eleven gods
>   whose home is
>   heaven, O ye eleven
>   who make earth your
>   dwelling,
>   Ye who with might,
>   eleven, live in waters,
>   accept this sacrifice, O
>   gods, with pleasure.
>
> – Translated by Ralph
>   T. H. Griffith
>   **—  Rigveda 1.139.11**

The story discribes it:—
As we know **Indra** spent 101 years with Prajapati uderstanding the self whereas the demon king from the first time getting an answer as the body is the self got away but indra came again and again to Prajapati after getting an answer and spend 101 years with Prajapati learning self and that's why gods are all prevalent.

CHANDOGYA UPNISHAD BOOK:VIII

> **SEVENTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. Prajapati said: 'The Self
>      which is free from sin, free
>      from old age, from death
>      and grief, from hunger and
>      thirst, which desires
>      nothing but what it ought
>      to desire, and imagines
>      nothing but what it ought
>      to imagine, that it is which
>      we must search out, that it
>      is which we must try to
>      understand. He who has
>      searched out that Self and
>      understands it, obtains all
>      worlds and all desires.'
> 2. The Devas (gods) and
>      Asuras (demons) both heard
>      these words, and said :
>      'Well, let us search for that
>      Self by which, if one has
>      searched it out, all worlds
>      and all desires are
>      obtained.'
>      Thus saying Indra went
>      from the Devas, Virokana
>      from the Asuras, and both,
>      without having
>      communicated with each
>      other, approached
>      Prajapati, holding fuel in
>      their hands, as is the
>      custom for pupils
>      approaching their master.
> 3. They dwelt there as
>      pupils for thirty-two years.
>      Then Prajapati asked them:
>      'For what purpose have you
>      both dwelt here?'
>      They replied: 'A saying of
>      yours is being repeated, viz.
>      "the Self which is free from
>      sin, free from old age, from
>      death and grief, from
>      hunger and thirst, which
>      desires nothing but what it
>      ought to desire, and
>      imagines nothing but what
>      it ought to imagine, that it
>      is which we must search
>      out, that it is which we
>      must try to understand. He
>      who has searched out that
>      Self and understands it,
>      obtains all worlds and all
>      desires." Now we both have
>      dwelt here because we wish
>      for that Self.'
>      Prajapati said to them: 'The
>      person that is seen in the
>      eye, that is the Self. This is
>      what I have said. This is
>      the immortal, the fearless,
>      this is Brahman.'
>      They asked: 'Sir, he who is
>      perceived in the water, and
>      he who is perceived in a
>      mirror, who is he?'
>      He replied: 'He himself
>      indeed is seen in all these
>      .'
>
> **EIGHTH KHANDA.**
>
> 1. 'Look at your Self in 
>      pan of water, and whatever
>      you do not understand of
>      your Self, come and tell
>      me.'
>      They looked in the water-
>      pan. Then Prajapati said to
>      them: 'What do you see?'
>      They said: 'We both see the
>      self thus altogether, a
>      picture even to the very
>      hairs and nails.'
> 2. Prajapati said to them:
>      'After you have adorned
>      yourselves, have put on
>      your best clothes and
>      cleaned yourselves, look
>      again into the water-pan.
>      They, after having adorned
>      themselves, having put on
>      their best clothes and
>      cleaned themselves, looked
>      into the water-pan.
>      Prajapati said: 'What do
>      you see?'
> 3. They said: 'Just as we
>      are, well adorned, with our
>      best clothes and clean, thus
>      we are both there, Sir, well
>      adorned, with our best
>      clothes and clean.'
>      Prajapati said: 'That is the
>      Self, this is the immortal,
>      the fearless, this is
>      Brahman.'
>      Then both went away
>      satisfied in their hearts.
>      **4. And Prajapati, looking
>      after them, said: 'They both
>      go away without having
>      perceived and without
>      having known the Self, and
>      whoever of these two,
>      whether Devas or Asuras,
>      will follow this doctrine
>      (upanishad), will perish.'
>      Now Virokana, satisfied in
>      his heart, went to the
>      Asuras and preached that
>      doctrine to them, that the
>      self (the body) alone is to
>      be worshipped, that the self
>      (the body) alone is to be
>      served, and that he who
>      worships the self and serves
>      the self, gains both worlds,
>      this and the next.**
>      **5. Therefore they call even
>      now a man who does not
>      give alms here, who has no
>      faith, and offers no
>      sacrifices, an Asura, for this
>      is the doctrine (upanishad)
>      of the Asuras. They deck
>      out the body of the dead
>      with perfumes, flowers, and
>      fine raiment by way of
>      ornament, and think they
>      will thus conquer that
>      world.**
>
> **NINTH KHANDA**
>
> **1. But Indra, before he had
>   returned to the Devas, saw
>   this difficulty. As this self
>   (the shadow in the water) is
>   well adorned, when the
>   body is well adorned, well
>   dressed, when the body is
>   well dressed, well cleaned,
>   if the body is well cleaned,
>   that self will also be blind,
>   if the body is blind, lame, if
>   the body is lame, crippled,
>   if the body is crippled, and
>   will perish in fact as soon
>   as the body perishes.
>   Therefore I see no good in
>   this (doctrine).**
>   2. Taking fuel in his hand
>   he came again as a pupil to
>   Prajapati. Prajapati said to
>   him: 'Maghavat (Indra), as
>   you went away with
>   Virokana, satisfied in your
>   heart, for what purpose did
>   you come back?'
>   He said : 'Sir, as this self
>   (the shadow) is well
>   adorned, when the body is
>   well adorned, well dressed,
>   when the body is well
>   dressed, well cleaned, if the
>   body is well cleaned, that
>   self will also be blind, if
>   the body is blind, lame, if
>   the body is lame, crippled,
>   if the body is crippled, and
>   will perish in fact as soon
>   as the body perishes.
>   Therefore I see no good in
>   this (doctrine).'
>   3. 'So it is indeed,
>   Maghavat,' replied
>   Prajapati; 'but I shall
>   explain him (the true Self)
>   further to
>   you. Live with me another
>   thirty-two years.'
>   He lived with him another
>   thirty-two years, and then
>   Pragapati said:
>
> **TENTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. 'He who moves about
>      happy in dreams, he is the
>      Self, this is the immortal,
>      the fearless, this is
>      Brahman.'
>      Then Indra went away
>      satisfied in his heart. But
>      before he had returned to
>      the Devas, he saw this
>      difficulty. Although it is
>      true that that self is not
>      blind, even if the body is
>      blind, nor lame, if the body
>      is lame, though it is true
>      that that self is not
>      rendered faulty by the
>      faults of it (the body),
> 2. Nor struck when it (the
>      body) is struck, nor lamed
>      when it is lamed, yet it is
>      as if they struck him (the
>      self) in dreams, as if they
>      chased him'. He becomes
>      even conscious, as it were,
>      of pain, and sheds tears.
>      Therefore I see no good in
>      this.
> 3. Taking fuel in his hands,
>      he went again as a pupil to
>      Prajapati. Prajapati said
>      to him: 'Maghavat, as you
>      went away satisfied in your
>      heart, for what purpose did
>      you come back?'
>      He said: 'Sir, although it is
>      true that that self is not
>      blind even if the body is
>      blind, nor lame, if the body
>      is lame, though it is true
>      that that self is not
>      rendered faulty by the
>      faults of it (the body),
> 4. Nor struck when it (the
>      body) is struck, nor lamed
>      when it is lamed, yet it is
>      as if they struck him (the
>      self) in dreams, as if they
>      chased him. He becomes
>      even conscious, as it were,
>      of pain, and sheds tears.
>      Therefore I see no good in
>      this.'
>      'So it is indeed, Maghavat,'
>      replied Prajapati; 'but I
>      shall explain him (the true
>      Self) further to you. Live
>      with me another thirty-two
>      years.' He lived with him
>      another thirty-two years.
>      Then Prajapati said:
>
> **ELEVENTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. 'When a man being
>      asleep, reposing, and at
>      perfect rest', sees no
>      dreams, that is the Self, this
>      is the immortal, the
>      fearless, this is Brahman.'
>      Then Indra went away
>      satisfied.in his heart. But
>      before he had returned to
>      the Devas, he saw this
>      difficulty. In truth he thus
>      does not know himself (his
>      self) that he is I, nor does
>      he know anything that
>      exists. He is gone to utter
>      annihilation. I see no good
>      in this.
> 2. Taking fuel in his hand
>      he went again as a pupil to
>      Prajapati. Prajapati said to
>      him: 'Maghavat, as you went
>      away satisfied in your heart,
>      for what purpose did you
>      come back?'
>      He said: 'Sir, in that way he
>      does not know himself (his
>      self ) that he is I, nor does
>      he know anything that
>      exists. He is gone to utter
>      annihilation. I see no good
>      in this.'
> 3. 'So it is indeed,
>      Maghavat,' replied Prajapati
>      'but I shall explain him (the
>      true Self) further to
>      you, and nothing more than
>      this . Live here otherfive
>      years.
>      **'He lived there other five
>      years. This made in all one
>      hundred and one years, and
>      therefore it is said that
>      Indra Maghavat lived one
>      hundred and one years as a
>      pupil with Prajapati.**
>      Prajapati said to him:
>
> **TWELFTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. 'Maghavat, this body is
>      mortal and always held by
>      death. It is the abode of
>      that Self which is immortal
>      and without body. When in
>      the body (by thinking this
>      body is I and I am this
>      body) the Self is held by
>      pleasure and pain. So long
>      as he is in the body, he
>      cannot get free from
>      pleasure and pain. But
>      when he is free of the body
>      (when he knows himself
>      different from the body),
>      then neither pleasure nor
>      pain touches him'.
> 2. 'The wind is without
>      body, the cloud, lightning,
>      and thunder are without
>      body (without hands, feet,
>      &c.) Now as these, arising
>      from this heavenly ether
>      (space), appear in their own
>      form, as soon as they have
>      approached the highest
>      light,
> 3. 'Thus does that serene
>      being, arising from this
>      body, appear in its own
>      form, as soon as it has
>      approached the highest
>      light (the knowledge of
>      Self) . He (in that state) is
>      the highest person (uttama
>      purusha). He moves about
>      there laughing (or eating),
>      playing, and rejoicing (in
>      his mind), be it with
>      women, carriages, or
>      relatives, never minding
>      that body into which he was
>      born.
>      'Like as a horse attached to
>      a cart, so is the spirit
>      (prana, pragnatman)
>      attached to this body.
> 4. 'Now where the sight has
>      entered into the void (the
>      open space, the black pupil
>      of the eye), there is the
>      person of the eye, the eye
>      itself is the instrument of
>      seeing. He who knows, let
>      me smell this, he is the
>      Self, the nose is the
>      instrument of smelling. He
>      who knows, let me say this,
>      he is the Self, the tongue is
>      the instrument of saying.
>      He who knows, let me hear
>      this, he is the Self, the ear
>      is the instrument of
>      hearing.
> 5. 'He who knows, let me
>      think this, he is the Self,
>      the mind is his divine eye .
>      He, the Self, seeing these
>      pleasures (which to others
>      are hidden like a buried
>      treasure of gold) through
>      his divine eye, i. e. the
>      mind, rejoices.
>      **'The Devas who are in the
>      world of Brahman meditate
>      on that Self (as taught by
>      Prajapati to Indra, and by
>      Indra to the Devas).
>      Therefore all worlds belong
>      to them, and all desires. He
>      who knows that Self and
>      understands it, obtains all
>      worlds and all desires.'**
>      Thus said Prajapati, yea,
>      thus said Prajapati.

link:—http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/chandogya.asp

**This is just my thinking you can believe in what you have got up with.**