# Are there any animal sacrifices specifically for Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, animals, yajna, sacrifice

There are animal sacrifices for Indra, Vayu, Agni, Prajapati and Shiva, etc in the Vedas.

For example, in the *Ashvalayana* Grihya Sutras:

> 1 1. Now the **spit-ox** (sacrificed to **Rudra**).
>
> 2. In autumn or in spring, under the (Nakshatra) Ârdrâ.
> 3. The best of his herd,
> 4. (An ox) which is neither leprous nor speckled;

In the Krishna Yajur Veda:

> The **barren goat** is connected with all the gods. To **Vayu** should
>   he offer it who desires wealth.
>
> To **sky and earth** should he offer it [the barren goat] who in
>   ploughing desires support.
>
> To **Agni and Soma** should he offer it who desires, 'May I be possessed
>   of food, an eater of food'.
>
> To **Sarasvati** should he offer it who, being able to utter speech,
>   cannot utter speech.
>
> To **Prajapati** should he offer it who desires, 'May I gain that which
>   has not been gained'.

Now, ancient Sri Vaishnava acharyas believe that Vishnu, since he is Brahman, is the actual recipient of sacrifices and not the Devas, so words like "Indra", "Agni", etc actually refer to Vishnu through either etymology (Indra means 'chief' or 'best') or through the principle known as *Samanadhikaranyam*, where the sacrifices actually propitiate the Devas, but Vishnu also who exists as the *Antaryami* of the Devas.

But my question is, are there any animal sacrifices *specifically* for Vishnu or Narayana by name?

Like any verses such as "He who desires prosperity should offer a goat to Vishnu"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Like any verses such as "He who desires prosperity should offer a goat
>   to Vishnu"?

Yes definitely we have such Mantras for Vishnu in the Krishna Yajurveda.

One I have already used in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23739/4732):

> DevAsurA eshu lokesh vaspardanta sa etam vishnurvAmanapashyattam swAyei devatAyA Ahalabhata tato vai sa imA .....||
>
> Once there was a conflict between the Devas and the Asuras regarding
>   some Vishya ( lokeshu vijaya bhuteshu i.e for gaining supremacy over
>   the worlds). Vishnu then had seen VAmana or "short in stature"
>   animals. Those (i.e such short statured animals) are then offered to
>   Vishnu. Thereafter Vishnu won over the three worlds. Thus, whoever
>    person (who's having conflicts regarding their possesions like houses, lands
>   etc), who offers such short animals to Vishnu can similarly
>   attain Vishnu-hood and win over the three worlds....
>
> **KYV 2nd KAnda, 1st PrapAthaka, 3rd AnuvAka**.

SAyanacharya in his commentary on this AnuvAka says:

> "Tritiya anuvAke jayAdihetun pashunanvidhitsannAdau lokatraya jaya
>   hetum pasum vidhAtum prastauti..."
>
> In this 3rd anuvAka, description of animals that are to be offered for the purpose of
>   winning over the three worlds, are being described...

Comment: So Vamana here means animals short in stature?  What kind of animals are those that Sayanacharya mentions?

Comment: You have Sayanacharya commentary? Kindly send to my mail if you have one.

Comment: Yes dwarf... No he does not mention that @Ikshvaku

Comment: Yes I hv Sayana, Mahidhara and some other commentaries on KYV and SYV .. I can't send u as I hv hard copies of YVs .. :) @NaveenKick

Comment: Do you have those commentaries in English?

Comment: I hv in Sanskrit+Bengali translation. @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury